# MATLAB: GUI suddenly zoomed-in and cropped

Tags: matlab, user-interface, zooming, crop, matlab-guide

I had a GUI made using GUIDE. Suddenly when I reopened MATLAB the GUI window got resized, zoomed-in and cropped, missing the top of it. This shows in GUIDE itself as well.

I'm using the same computer and MATLAB version. I already tried to restart MATLAB and the computer itself.

The only thing I can think of that changed is a second monitor I was using, but I tried plugging it in and out, and it didn't help.
This doesn't happen in other GUIs I'm using.

Specs:
Windows 8, MATLAB R2013a, 1920x1080 screen resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `units` of all the controls to `normalized`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB sizes GUIs based on system information about the size of the screen, so adding a second monitor could change that system information and confuse MATLAB. You could test if that is what caused the problem by unplugging the new monitor and restarting the computer/program.

For one project I had to change the units on everything to characters so that it would size appropriately for various screen sizes. Normalized should work too, however, it won't revert the gui to how it was before it got jacked up, only keep it from changing again.

So, try reverting to your original screen configuration and restarting the computer. If that resolves the problem, change your units to normalized or characters.

Comment: Thank you. I already did what you suggested, but it didn't fix the problem.